# How can I remove Jetstream from my laravel 8 project?

Tags: laravel-8

I install Jetstream few mins ago in my Laravel project. But I thinks it  hampers my project So I want remove it. Is that possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.